# If $A$ and $B$ are events such that $P(A\mid B)=P(B\mid A)$, then

Tags: probability

If $A$ and $B$ are events such that $P(A\mid B)=P(B\mid A)$, then

(A) $A \subset B$ but $A \neq B$

(B) $A=B$

(C) $A \cap B = \emptyset $

(D) $P(A)= P(B)$

**My try**

It is given that $P(A\mid B)=P(B\mid A)$

$ \implies \dfrac {P\left( A\cap B\right) }{P\left( B\right) } =\dfrac {P\left( B\cap A\right) }{P\left( A\right) }$

$\implies ( P\left( A\cap B\right))(P(A)-P(B))=0$

$\implies \  either \ P(A)=P(B) \ or \ P(A\cap B)=0$

$\implies \  either \ P(A)=P(B) \ or \ A\cap B=\emptyset$

**But the correct answer is P(A)=P(B)**

Can anyone explain why $A\cap B=\emptyset$ is wrong?

Comment: When you write $\phi$ (phi), do you mean $\emptyset$ (empty set)? If so, I think your logic is sound.

Comment: Your approach looks good. It is indeed possible that $A\cap B=\varnothing$; consider an experiment of flipping a coin where $A=\text{flipped heads}$ and $B=\text{flipped tails}$.

Comment: Your analysis is sound. Even with the incorrect implication at the end, you are pointing out, essentially correctly, that neither **(C)** nor **(D)** necessarily follows from the given equality. If $P(A \cap B) = 0$, the equality is satisfied even if $P(A) \neq P(B)$. The conclusion is that the question you were asked to answer is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic implies, either $\mathbb{P}[A] = \mathbb{P}[B]$ or $\mathbb{P}[A \cap B] = 0$. Certainly, if $A \cap B = \emptyset$ the second condition holds, but consider $A \cap B$ being some discrete event out of a continuous probability, so $A \cap B \ne \emptyset$ but $\mathbb{P}[A\cap B] = 0$...

Thus it is *possible* (i.e. sufficient) that $A\cap B = \emptyset$ but it is not really necessary, and your question's style clearly implies a necessary condition...

Comment: Indeed the fully correct answer is: $\mathsf P(A\mid B)=\mathsf P(B\mid A)\implies \mathsf P(A)=\mathsf P(B)~\lor~\mathsf P(A\cap B)=0$, but $\mathsf P(A\cap B)=0\require{cancel}\cancel\implies A\cap B=\emptyset$

Answer (score 1):

You can suposse that we have the space $\Omega = [-1, 1]\times [-1, 1]$ and the events $A = [0, 1]\times [0, 1]$ and $B = [-1, 0]\times[-1, 0]$. It's clear that $A\cap B = \{(0, 0)\}$. If you consider the geometric probability, then $P(A)=P(B)=1/4$ and $P(A\cap B) = 0$ and you can see that $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider an experiment:
Pick a number uniformly from the interval $[0,1]$.

Let the event

$A =$ The picked number is $\leq 0.5$, and

$B =$ The picked number is $\geq 0.5$.

Here $P(A \cap B) = P$(the picked number is .5) = 0 (property of continious uniform random variable). Hope this example works.

Answer (score -2):

Hello Girish Kumar chandora that's a good try but you just missed the point close
What you did is correct to an extent but you have taken 
 $P(A∩B)$as common but think about this
If it is given that $P(A∩B)/P(B)=P(B∩A)/P(A)$ 
Then the $P(A∩B)$ would be cancelled on both L.H.S and R.H.S as they both are same (basic rule in division)
So then u will be left behind with 
$P(A)=P(B)$

Comment: $P(A\cap B)$ can only be "cancelled" if it is nonzero, an assumption that is precisely the OP's question.

Comment: The OP's work is certainly more correct than yours (even though it is not perfect). Best to delete your answer - it will not help anyone.